# SOAP Endpoint doesn't retrieve WSDL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

So I have my main class:

```
public class ProjectEndpoint{

    private String URI = "http://localhost:1212/";

    public ProjectEndpoint() {

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting Server " + URI);

        Endpoint entityEndpoint = Endpoint.create(new Entity());

        entityEndpoint.publish(URI + "Entity");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            ProjectEndpoint ss = new ProjectEndpoint();
            ss.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the real endpoint file:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import pt.project.projectSOAPMiddleware.models.Evaluate.EntityEvaluationRequest;
import pt.project.projectSOAPMiddleware.models.Evaluate.EvaluateEntityOnline;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@WebService
// @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@EnableWs
public class Entity {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName());

    @WebMethod
    public String EntityCreated(@WebParam(partName = "name", name = "name") String name) {
        return "OK";
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String EntityUpdated(@WebParam(partName = "name", name = "name") String name) {
        return "OK";
    }

    @WebMethod
    public int EvaluateEntityOnline(@XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(partName = "Number_Ext", name = "Number_Ext") String Number_Ext,
                                    @XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(partName = "Name", name = "Name") String Name,
                                    @XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(partName = "EntityCategory", name = "EntityCategory") String EntityCategory,
                                    @XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(partName = "EntityType", name = "EntityType") String EntityType,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "BirthDate", name = "BirthDate") String BirthDate,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Gender", name = "Gender") String Gender,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "MaritalStatus", name = "MaritalStatus") String MaritalStatus,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Nationality", name = "Nationality") String Nationality,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Nationality2", name = "Nationality2") String Nationality2,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Nationality3", name = "Nationality3") String Nationality3,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "ResidenceCode", name = "ResidenceCode") String ResidenceCode,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "BirthPlace", name = "BirthPlace") String BirthPlace,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "ConstitutionDate", name = "ConstitutionDate") String ConstitutionDate,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Profession", name = "Profession") String Profession,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "ProfessionalActivity", name = "ProfessionalActivity") String ProfessionalActivity,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "EducationalQualifications", name = "EducationalQualifications") String EducationalQualifications,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "SectorialCode", name = "SectorialCode") String SectorialCode,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "SocialCapital", name = "SocialCapital") BigDecimal SocialCapital,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "EntityIncome", name = "EntityIncome") BigDecimal EntityIncome,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Parent1Name", name = "Parent1Name") String Parent1Name,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Parent2Name", name = "Parent2Name") String Parent2Name,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Currency", name = "Currency") String Currency,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "CAE", name = "CAE") String CAE,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "CAE2", name = "CAE2") String CAE2,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "CAE3", name = "CAE3") String CAE3,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "SocietyType", name = "SocietyType") String SocietyType,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "StockMarketCode", name = "StockMarketCode") String StockMarketCode,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "CreatedAt_Ext", name = "CreatedAt_Ext") String CreatedAt_Ext,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "RequestUser", name = "RequestUser") String RequestUser,
                                    @XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(partName = "action", name = "action") String action,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "IsPEPDeclared", name = "IsPEPDeclared") boolean IsPEPDeclared,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "IsPEPDescription", name = "IsPEPDescription") String IsPEPDescription,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "IsPresencial", name = "IsPresencial") boolean IsPresencial,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "ImportDate", name = "ImportDate") String ImportDate,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Flexfields", name = "Flexfields") String Flexfields,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "DocumentList", name = "DocumentList") String DocumentList,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "ContactList", name = "ContactList") String ContactList,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "Photo", name = "Photo") byte[] Photo,
                                    @WebParam(partName = "BeneficialOwnersList", name = "BeneficialOwnersList") String BeneficialOwnersList) {
        if(Number_Ext == null || Name == null || EntityCategory == null || EntityType == null || action == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {

            do stuff here...

            return 1;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Some error occurred while running EvaluateEntityOnline: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I search on the endpoint **https://localhost:1212/Entity?wsdl** it returns the following instead of a WSDL document:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.3.1 svn-revision#6ef5f7eb9a938dbc4562f25f8fa0b67cc4ff2dbb.  -->
<!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.3.1 svn-revision#6ef5f7eb9a938dbc4562f25f8fa0b67cc4ff2dbb.  -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/" name="EntityService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:1212/Entity?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="EvaluateEntityOnline">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EvaluateEntityOnline"/>
</message>
<message name="EvaluateEntityOnlineResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EvaluateEntityOnlineResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="EntityCreated">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EntityCreated"/>
</message>
<message name="EntityCreatedResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EntityCreatedResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="EntityUpdated">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EntityUpdated"/>
</message>
<message name="EntityUpdatedResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:EntityUpdatedResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="Entity">
<operation name="EvaluateEntityOnline">
<input wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EvaluateEntityOnlineRequest" message="tns:EvaluateEntityOnline"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EvaluateEntityOnlineResponse" message="tns:EvaluateEntityOnlineResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="EntityCreated">
<input wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EntityCreatedRequest" message="tns:EntityCreated"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EntityCreatedResponse" message="tns:EntityCreatedResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="EntityUpdated">
<input wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EntityUpdatedRequest" message="tns:EntityUpdated"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://endpoints.ProjectSOAPMiddleware.Project.pt/Entity/EntityUpdatedResponse" message="tns:EntityUpdatedResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="EntityPortBinding" type="tns:Entity">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="EvaluateEntityOnline">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="EntityCreated">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="EntityUpdated">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="EntityService">
<port name="EntityPort" binding="tns:EntityPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:1212/Entity"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

How can I retrieve a WSDL instead of this? I've tried different ways to solve it, but never succeeded. In the tutorial that I found online they have a WSDL file allocated somewhere, but I want it to be generated with the class that I have (in this case the Entity class).

Comment: It is a proper WSDL

Comment: Its almost what I want, but I need to have the "wsdl" namespace. And I added "@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)"

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov